# cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined Google Maps

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, maps

I am using google maps and want to only show the map if something is true.

HTML:

```
 <div *ngIf="anyboolToShowMapOrNot" #map id="map"></div>
```

my Typescript code:

```
  @ViewChild("map",{static: true}) mapElement:ElementRef;
  map: any;
  constructor(private shareService: ShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.initMap();

  }
  initMap(){
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement,this.shareService.getMapOptions(google))
    for(let i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
     this.addMarker(this.map,i,i,"jow sicha");
    }
  }
```

Without the ngIf the map works without any problems. But with the ngIf I get the following Error:

Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the `{static: true}` for your `@ViewChild`, the value won't be updated dynamically, and you need dynamic updating when `*ngIf` can bring an element in and out of existence.

When you're using `{static: false}`, you have to be careful with timing, and make sure your variable has actually been updated before you use it.

One useful trick for knowing when a `@ViewChild` value has been updated is to use a getter/setter.

```
private _mapElement: ElementRef;

@ViewChild("map", {static: false}) get mapElement(): ElementRef { return this._mapElement; }
set mapElement(newValue: ElementRef) {
  if (this._mapElement !== newValue) {
    this._mapElement = newValue;
    // Check that newValue is a defined value, and possibly perform actions here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with another problem?  I am using ion segment, on one side I use a List and on the other side I want to show my Map, I put my initMap function inside the set mapElement, to be sure it only gets triggered when the mapelement is filled. But now I got the same error again.

Comment: <div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">
      <div #map id="map"></div>
  </div>     I think there is a problem? Because if I put the map outside of the switch it works to load the map, even if init() only gets triggert when the segment changes

Comment: I'm a bit confused (perhaps it's because I haven't worked with Ion), but I'm not sure what `init()` function you're referring to. There's definitely the same issue at hand, however, when using `*ngSwitchCase` as there is with `*ngIf` -- DOM elements are dynamically created and destroyed.